# How to run ts_stat for each row

Tags: postgresql

I have a table 'posts' like below,

`id | title    |    description
---+----------+---------------------------------------------
 1 | title1   | A short description about title1
 2 | title2   | this is about title2
 3 | title2   | this is some other description
 4 | title1   | this is different from previous description`

There are two questions,

1. I need to get the counts of each word for all descriptions of a given title. I tried using `ts_stat()` but it is giving me word frequency for the complete column (irrespective of which title it belongs to).

   `select ts_stat($$select to_tsvector('simple', posts.description) from posts$$);`

   Looking for some help on creating a new table with each row as title, word, count.
2. Initially I was thinking of creating rows as, (title, comma separated word and its count) as columns but getting the count of a word for a given title may need some additional work so thought of adding a new row for each word for every title.

Please let me know if there are any better methods to achieve this.

`version: PostgreSQL 9.5.8`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not think anything less monstrous then

```
t=# with c as (
  select to_tsvector('simple',unnest(string_to_array(description,' '))),title
  from posts
)
, d as (
  select translate(split_part(to_tsvector::text,':',1),$$'$$,'') ts,title
  from c
  where octet_length(to_tsvector::text) > 0
)
select ts,title,count(1)
from d
group by title,ts
order by 1;
     ts      |   title    | count
-------------+------------+-------
 a           |  title1    |     1
 about       |  title1    |     1
 about       |  title2    |     1
 description |  title1    |     2
 description |  title2    |     1
 different   |  title1    |     1
 from        |  title1    |     1
 is          |  title2    |     2
 is          |  title1    |     1
 other       |  title2    |     1
 previous    |  title1    |     1
 short       |  title1    |     1
 some        |  title2    |     1
 this        |  title1    |     1
 this        |  title2    |     2
 title1      |  title1    |     1
 title2      |  title2    |     1
(17 rows)
```

which reconciles with:

```
t=# select ts_stat('select to_tsvector($$simple$$,description) from posts') order by 1 ;
      ts_stat
-------------------
 (a,1,1)
 (about,2,2)
 (description,3,3)
 (different,1,1)
 (from,1,1)
 (is,3,3)
 (other,1,1)
 (previous,1,1)
 (short,1,1)
 (some,1,1)
 (this,3,3)
 (title1,1,1)
 (title2,1,1)
(13 rows)
```

but again - my experience with FTS is very limited - may be you can do it neater with ts_functions